# Returning an xml as string, but when I print it, all start tags are ignored PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, rest

im trying to read an xml as a string that i get from a json from a webservice, when I check the request the xml looks fine, but when I print said json from php, all the start tags are ignored. Is there a reason for this behavior?

```
{
    "response": "ok",
    "xmlData": "<Tag1><Tag2>data</Tag2><Tag3><Tag4>data</Tag4></Tag3></tag1>"
}
```

php output:

```
{
    "response":"ok",
    "xmlData":"data<\/Tag2>data<\/tag4><\/Tag3><\/tag1>"
}

function webPostRequest($resourceURL, $postContent)
{
    $url = $resourceURL;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postContent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: There's probably something wrong in your code.

Comment: Can you include the PHP code that outputs the xml data?

Comment: Im only outputting the result from the curl call to the webservice, no xml parsing has happened

Comment: show how you're printing that text. php has no clue what json is - it's just plain text, php will NOT mangle a text string and strip out opening tags and escape out the `/` in closing tags on its own. something ELSE is doing that.

Comment: added how I'm printing the text, just a simple echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings.

htmlspecialchars() is what you need to fix this