# json_encode return some weird characters

Tags: php, json, twitter, utf-8

I'm trying to grab data from twitter. I'm success to return data to array. BUt, when i change it to json using json_encode, some data have weird characters.

```
{
   "name": "\u24d7\u24d8\u24db",
   "url": "http:\/\/t.co\/m3rqX58egq",
}
```

what's wrong? is it related to utf8 encode and JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is related to JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES and it is available since PHP 5.4.0.

return json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the Special characters coming back in the JSON, Have a look at htmlSpecialChars() [Or see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974127/returning-an-xml-as-string-but-when-i-print-it-all-start-tags-are-ignored-php/32974233#32974233)